# How do I match any number preceding a specified word, regardless of comma and decimal characters?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

How do I pull all the numbers (including the commas and decimal chars) from the following example source. In this example I want "2,078", "1.07", "1.1", and "1" to match.

> 4 beds 3 full , 1 half baths 2,078 sq ft 1.07 widget 1.1 widget 1 widget 1,000 widgets

This is what I have so far:

```
(\d{1,3}(.?\d{2})?)(?=\swidget)
```

..and a screenshot of the results in regexr:

[image]

Comment: Why `2,078` must match, it is not followed by `widget`?

Comment: There should be 2 `1`s found, right? `1 widget` then  `1,000 widgets`. Also the `.` should be escaped if that is suppose to be a decimal in your regex.

Comment: If you want `1.1` to be matched, why did you put `\d{2}` and not `\d+`?

Comment: There are too many specific differences in the numbers you want. The easiest way is to split on spaces and take your chances from there. Loop the array, If a widget is the next element, take this one, if 'sq' and 'ft' are the next two elements, take this one, etc..

Comment: @mattmiller, With "all the numbers" you are selecting 1, but not the first 4 and next 3, what do you actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want:

```
\D(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?)(?=\swidget)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\D                  : a non digit
(                   : start group 1
    \d{1,3}         : 1 to 3 digits
    (?:,\d{3})*     : 0 or more comma and 3 digits
    (?:\.\d{1,2})?  : 0 or 1 dot and 1 or 2 digit
)                   : end group 1
(?=\swidget)        : followed by space and widget
```

[See in action](https://regex101.com/r/lD2jU4/1)